# NodeJs : Reference Error : (my own var) not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Trying to require and use a module in my router file. I have managed to require it (I think) but now it says the following error:**

> ReferenceError: USERS is not defined    at
>   c:\work\nodejs\router\main.js:32:19    at Layer.handle [as
>   handle_request]
>   (c:\work\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)    at
>   next (c:\work\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13) 
>   at Route.dispatch
>   (c:\work\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)    at
>   Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (c:\work\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)    at
>   c:\work\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22    at
>   Function.proto.process_params
>   (c:\work\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)    at
>   next (c:\work\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10) 
>   at c:\work\nodejs\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:111:5    at
>   IncomingMessage.onEnd
>   (c:\work\nodejs\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:136:7)

**where USERS is an object containing an array of objects as follows:**

```
//users.js
module.exports = function () {

// Create User prototype and objects
var USERS = { users: [] };

function User(type, useremail, password) {
 this.type = type;
 this.useremail = useremail;
 this.password = password;
}

var Bob = new User("rep", "bob@bob.com", "qwerty");
USERS.users.push(Bob);

var Helen = new User("rep", "helen@helen.com", "test");
USERS.users.push(Helen);

var Dominic = new User("customer", "dom@dom.com", "1234");
USERS.users.push(Dominic);

var James = new User("grower", "james@james.com", "pass1");
USERS.users.push(James);

};
```

**My router code is:**

```
var url = require('url'); var users = require('./router/users.js');

module.exports = function (app) {

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index.html');
        console.log("Home page displayed");
    });

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
        res.render('login.html');
        console.log("Log in page displayed");

    });

app.get('/api/orders/:id', function (req, res) {
      console.log(req.params.id); 
      res.json(ORDER.orders[req.params.id]);
    });

    app.get('/api/orders/', function (req, res) {
      console.log(ORDER); 
      res.json(ORDER);

    });      app.get('/api/users/:id', function (req, res) {
      console.log(req.params.id); 
      res.json(USERS.users[req.params.id]);
    });

    app.get('/api/users/', function (req, res) {
      console.log(USERS); 
      res.json(USERS);

    });
```

**How do I correctly reference USERS in this case in my router?**

Comment: You would have to export `USERS` in the module or in the function to reference it from the outside.

Comment: You are not exporting `USERS`

Comment: @AvraamMavridis How do I do that? I have tried putting module.exports = function (USERS) { } around it all as well as module.exports = USERS; at the end

Comment: @hturner see answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//users.js


// Create User prototype and objects
var USERS = { users: [] };

function User(type, useremail, password) {
 this.type = type;
 this.useremail = useremail;
 this.password = password;
}

var Bob = new User("rep", "bob@bob.com", "qwerty");
USERS.users.push(Bob);

var Helen = new User("rep", "helen@helen.com", "test");
USERS.users.push(Helen);

var Dominic = new User("customer", "dom@dom.com", "1234");
USERS.users.push(Dominic);

var James = new User("grower", "james@james.com", "pass1");
USERS.users.push(James);

};

module.exports = USERS
```

or even better:

```
var getUsers = function(){ return Users.users;};
var addUser = function(name, email, somethingelse)
 { 
  var u = new User(name, email, somethingeelse); 
  Users.users.push(u);
};

module.exports = {
   getUsers: getUsers,
   addUser: addUser
}
```

Comment: I've just given an up vote. I found your answer easy to understand and it solved my error.